# SQL Server Full-Text-Index Search does not work

Tags: sql-server

The full-text-index searches are not returning the expected results. The index is built by now, but not finding some really basic strings.

This query does not return the user called `"Other 11"`.

```sql
SELECT KEY_TBL.RANK, FT_TBL.Firstname
FROM [user].[User] AS FT_TBL
         INNER JOIN
     CONTAINSTABLE([user].[User], Firstname,
                   '"Other*"') AS KEY_TBL
     ON FT_TBL.UserId = KEY_TBL.[KEY]
ORDER BY KEY_TBL.RANK DESC
GO
```

If I rewrite the query like this, it will work and return the user called `"Other 11"`.

```sql
SELECT KEY_TBL.RANK, FT_TBL.Firstname
FROM [user].[User] AS FT_TBL
         INNER JOIN
     CONTAINSTABLE([user].[User], Firstname,
                   '"Other 11"') AS KEY_TBL
     ON FT_TBL.UserId = KEY_TBL.[KEY]
ORDER BY KEY_TBL.RANK DESC
GO
```

Something similar happens with `FREETEXTTABLE` and `CONTAINS` with a predicate search is also not working.

What could be the reason for this behavior?

Comment: On a second thought, probably the word `Other` is in a STOPLIST which causes it to not be contained in the Full-Text-Index.

Answer (score 1):

Other and 11 are two differents words.

With a FTS predicate like '"Other*"' you will find "Otherwise" but never "Other 11"

You need to use a NEAR predicate like :

```
'NEAR((Other, 11),1, TRUE)'
```